# Why view elements are going out of the page

Tags: android

I have a keyword search option with EditView and a button in my android app, which in ADT looks perfect.

But when i run the program, the EditView expand beyond the viewing area and search button disappears because it goes out of page.

Xml for this is:

```
<TableRow 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/detail_ll"
           style="@style/search_bg_style"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

           <EditText
               android:id="@+id/keyword_detail"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="0.7"
               android:ems="10"
               android:hint="@string/keyword" />

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/button_search"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="0.3"
               android:text="@string/search" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>
```

Please help me in getting this in viewing area..

Comment: do you really need to use a TableRow? can you provide a screenshot of what it's supposed to look like (and what it looks like now on the device)

Comment: problem solved by removing linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

can you post the entire xml?
i mean with the

```
<TableLayout />
```

main tag

try setting android 
android:layout_weight="1"

for both

or try android:layout_weight="1.5"

for edit text and
android:layout_weight="0.5"
  for the button

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make the  `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"` or any fixed width (in dps) in the `TableRow` element.

`layout_weight` attribute divides a pre-known space according to its weight which is not present in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to TableRow and LinearLayout height MatchParent and
give Weightsum="1" to LinearLayout it will fixed your problem and also remove android:ems property from Edittext

Hope this Help you.